# See organic visitors per hour graph in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to get a chart in Google Analytics that will show the organic visitors on a given day by the hour?

I know you can do this for all traffic, but couldn't see how to do it for organic traffic only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a segment to view any report with the filter you are looking for. When you click segments, Organic Traffic is one of the default segments already pre-defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Custom Report that will display this for you.
The metric is Sessions, the Dimension is Hour of Day. Filter for medium = Organic.